# Android module and library bidirectional communication

Tags: android, android-library, android-module

I have an android application in which I have an app moduleand a social module.

The social module is implemented as an android library

[image] 
In my app modules' build.gradle I have mentioned `implementation project(':social')` which helps me invoke the library's activities from my app module.

However I now need to invoke some activities of the app module from the social module.

I went into the social modules build.gradle and wrote `implementation project(':app')` however I was greeted with some errors which did not made much connection with me. I was expecting some errors of cyclic dependencies perhaps that show up however I get errors like the following

[image]

How should I go about calling activities belonging to my app module from the social library module